# Is there only numerical method to find this defenite integral or any other way?

Tags: definite-integrals

Is there only numerical method to find this integral or any other way? Any references or links would be helpful.

> $$\int _{a} ^ {b} e ^ {-x^2/2} dx .$$

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants

Comment: You can get an answer in terms of error function.

Comment: and erf is a special function.

Comment: @experimentX I have seen tables to evaluate this integrals, which imply that it can only be evaluated using numerical methods right?And what does you mean by special function?

Comment: table is like a calculator to know it's value like you used log tables back in old days when there weren't any calculators. For special functions, [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_functions). Erf or error function is just a type of special function in long list of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer

> $$\int_{a}^{b}e^{-x^2/2}dx= \sqrt {\frac{\pi}{2} }\left({{\rm erf}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-{{\rm erf}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}\right),$$

where $\rm erf(x)$ is the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

> $$ \operatorname{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^x e^{-t^2}\,\mathrm dt.  $$

Comment: Sir, But I was looking for a number.

Comment: @dexterdev: You will get a number once you specify $a$ and $b$. Also, note that, this is a special function not an elementary function.

Comment: Benghoral : But how do we find error function. Is there any method to calculate this integral.

Comment: ok got it...Error function is evaluated using McLaurin series.