# Calculating an integral

Tags: integration

> Let $r>0$. Show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int\limits^{-r}_{-\infty} \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4t}\right) dx=\frac{1}{2}\left[1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{4t}}\right)\right]$$
>   where $\text{erf}$ is [the  error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)

I calculated this using software, but I can't prove .... somebody can help me please.

Comment: You may want to google the keyword *error function*.

Comment: @sos440 What error? I dont understand ...

Comment: This function is related to what is known as the error function. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @Wmmoreno: just google the words as sos440 said.

Comment: @user71352 hann ... ok tnks XD

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503643/is-there-only-numerical-method-to-find-this-defenite-integral-or-any-other-way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the integrand is even, we have
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int\limits^{-r}_{-\infty} \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4t}\right) dx
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int\limits^{\infty}_{r} \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4t}\right) dx.
\end{align}$$
Then, making the $u$-substitution $u=x/(2\sqrt{t})$, we get
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int\limits^{-r}_{-\infty} \exp \left(-\frac{x^{2}}{4t}\right) dx
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits^{\infty}_{r/(2\sqrt{t})} \exp \left(-u^2\right) du\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int\limits_0^\infty\exp \left(-u^2\right) du -  \operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{r}{2\sqrt{t}}\right) \right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left[1-\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{r}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)\right].
\end{align}$$