# Fourier coefficients of the Gaussian.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

I would need to find the fourier coefficient of this gaussian for a problem. I'm now stuck with this integral, 
\begin{equation}
c_{n}=\int_{-1}^{1}e^{\frac{x^{2}}{2}}\left(\cos\left(\pi nx\right)\right)dx.
\end{equation}
I'm not sure if it is possible an analytical solution, does anybody know? Please note that's on an interval and not on the whole line.

Comment: Have you tried mathematica or maple?

Comment: I'm not really good at neither... any way I would like to know if it exists a way for solving it analytically before switching to numerically...

Comment: The integral is not elementary!  You can have an answer in terms of the error function.  See [here] (http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Int%28exp%28x%5E2%2F2%29cos%28+n%5Cpi+x%29%2C+x%3D-1..+1%29&x=12&y=7).

Comment: thank you very much... I was afraid it wasn't plain...

Comment: You are very welcome! By the way where did this problem come from?

Comment: I was trying to find an function that could be easy to write in Fourier Expansion and Hermite Expansion at the same time, maybe I could ask this question directly...

Comment: Here is a useful [integral](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503643/is-there-only-numerical-method-to-find-this-defenite-integral-or-any-other-way) for you