# How to solve this equation with error functions?

Tags: integration, statistics

I'd like to solve the following equation for $S$, in terms of $p, x,$ and $\sigma$:

$$
p = \int_0^x\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \frac{e^{\frac{-(S-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)- \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S-1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)} d\mu
$$

Solving the integral as Mhenni suggested yields:
$$
p = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\left(\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S-x}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) - \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right) \right)}{{\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)- \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S-1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}}
$$

The problem now is dealing with the $S$'s inside the error functions. I know there's an inverse error function ($\mathrm{erf}^{-1}$), but I don't see how this is ultimately solvable for $S$.

Is this possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Make change of variables $(S-\mu) /(\sqrt{2}\sigma)  =t$ and then use the erf function.

Comment: So then I would be integrating with respect to $t$, since $t$ would contain $\mu$?

Comment: You will be integrating with respect to $t$!  It is just a change of variables! Do you know how make integration but substitution?

Comment: It's been a while but yes. But I'm not sure how to integrate the error function.

Comment: What are you doing?  The denominator does not depend on $\mu$? Also you need to change the limits of integration too! By the way where did this problem come from?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, removed that edit. This makes a lot more sense now, and I can just pull the error functions out of the integral. Thanks! Solving for S will still depend on using the inverse error function after dealing with the integral, so I'm still not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that there are some typo's.

The result I obtained is $$p=\sigma\frac{  \text{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{S-x}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)}{\text{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2} \sigma
   }\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{S-1}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)}$$ I do not think that you could be able to solve analytically the equation for $S$. More than likely, only numerical methods could do it.

If you provide some typical values for $p,\sigma,x$, I could look at some numerical scheme.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The constraints are $0 \leq p \leq 1$, $0 < \sigma \leq 1$, $0 \leq x \leq 1$, not sure if that helps.

Comment: You are welcome ! Again, I cannot imagine any anlytical solution. If you want, give me one value for each of the three parameters.

Answer (score -4):

You have not changed to limits of integration

> $$
> p = \frac{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} }{   {\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)- \mathrm{erf}\left(\frac{S-1}{\sqrt{2}\sigma}\right)}} 
>    \int_{S/(\sqrt{2}{\sigma}) }^{  (S-x) /(\sqrt{2}{\sigma}) } e^{-t^2} dt. 
> $$

**Added:** You need my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503643/is-there-only-numerical-method-to-find-this-defenite-integral-or-any-other-way) to finish evaluating the integral.

Comment: Right, sorry, fixed that I think. This should be $dt$, right? I'm imagining though that once I solve the integral I still may not be able to solve the equation for $S$.

Comment: Can you find the inverse of the erf function?

Comment: Yes, such a function [exists](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseErf.html)

Comment: I am talking about the existence!  What I mean is can you find it as a closed form?

Comment: So I believe you are done!

Comment: I don't think it exists in closed form, no. I think to solve this I would need a way to combine all of the $S$'s into the argument of a single error function, and then take the inverse of that.

Comment: See what I added.

Comment: I think I've managed to solve the integral (see edits to the original question). The issue now is that there are 4 error functions all with $S$ as an argument.

Comment: "You need my answer to finish evaluating the integral." Well, no, simply the *definition* of the erf function.

Comment: @Did I do not have time to waste!

Comment: Is this lack of "time to waste" the reason why you post wrong and/or misleading answers on the site? I am not following.

Comment: To users please pay attention to some users who have had a problem with my answers!

Comment: What's the downvote for?